# Oracle group by, take first element from non-grouped column

Tags: oracle, group-by, aggregate

I'm quite new to Oracle and I recently ran into a problem :

I have a table with the following columns : person_id, account_login, add_date.

```
person_id | account_login | add_date
----------|---------------|------------
1         | user1         | 2012-07-10
1         | user2         | 2012-07-09
2         | user3         | 2012-07-05
2         | user4         | 2012-07-04
```

A person can have multiple account_logins. For every person, I want to fetch the oldest account_login :

```
person_id | account_login | add_date
----------|---------------|------------
1         | user2         | 2012-07-09
2         | user4         | 2012-07-04
```

So what I did was :

```
select
  person_id,
  MAX(account_login) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY add_date)
from
  table
group by
  person_id;
```

I get exactly the result I want, but I think the syntax of my query is far from good.. Oracle forces me to use an aggregate function and I used MAX() or MIN() knowing that it's completely senseless..

Is there a way to write the query better than this? (Oracle 11g)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DENSE_RANK as an analytic alone, and select from the resulting query:

```
SELECT person_id, account_login, add_date
  FROM (SELECT table.*
             , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY add_date) rnk
         FROM table)
 WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Not sure which version you consider more elegant. It also does not address what to do if you have two accounts created on the same date for a particular person_id. If you've also got a time component in your add_date then you should be okay. If ties are likely, perhaps ROW_NUMBER() would give you a more desirable outcome.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I consider it more elegant than mine because there is no part that makes no sense (unlike my query). And yes, there is a time component. So this will work fine. Sorry, I forgot to mention that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table and the nested view like this

```
select person_id,account_login,add_date
from tab inner join 
(select person_id,min(add_date) add_date 
from tab group by person_id) 
using(person_id,add_date)
```

BTW,I really don't think this is clearly.